# Missing swagger REST descriptions for Web Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I followed the guide here: http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/25/asp-net-web-api-documentation-using-swagger/

I put in the following XML comments:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Add new student
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="student">Student Model</param>
    /// <remarks>Insert new student</remarks>
    /// <response code="400">Bad request</response>
    /// <response code="500">Internal Server Error</response>
```

Why do I not get any descriptions? The response codes don't show up either.
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Did you generate the XML file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enable XML documentation for your subproject (from project properties / build) like you have for your Web API project. Except this time, route it directly to XmlDocument.xml so that it gets generated in your project's root folder.

Comment: Thank you for this, the XmlDocument.xml suggestion is what made it all work. The guide made it seem as if my typical XmlDocument.xml for api comments and swagger xml (WebApiSwagger.xml) were two different files whereas I was supposed to use the same XML file for both situations.

Comment: No problem, you teach me about Swagger, I've been using the default by Visual Studio :)